# Android animated TabLayout dot

Tags: android, android-animation, android-tablayout

I want to animate TabLayout dot indicator to stretch it on selected state. I used default animation to do that but its bugged and it cant take default shape by animating width only. After animation its stretched to rectangle and I don't understand why.

Code:

```
    val vg = tabLayout.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object: TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager){
        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {}
        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
            val tabDot = vg.getChildAt(tab.position)
            tabDot?.let { v->
                animateDotWidthDefault(v)
                animateDotColor(v, R.color.selected_blue, R.color.default_grey)
            }
        }
        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
            val tabDot = vg.getChildAt(tab.position)
            tabDot?.let { v->
                animateDotWidthStretch(v)
                animateDotColor(v, R.color.default_grey, R.color.selected_blue)
            }
        }
    })

 private fun animateDotWidthDefault(tabDot: View){
        val widthAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(stretchedWidth, defaultWidth)
        widthAnimator.duration = 500
        widthAnimator.interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
        widthAnimator.addUpdateListener { animation ->
            tabDot.layoutParams.width = animation.animatedValue as Int
            tabDot.requestLayout()
        }
        widthAnimator.start()
    }

    private fun animateDotWidthStretch(tabDot: View){
        val widthAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(defaultWidth, stretchedWidth)
        widthAnimator.duration = 500
        widthAnimator.interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator()
        widthAnimator.apply {
            addUpdateListener { animation ->
                tabDot.layoutParams.width = animation.animatedValue as Int
                tabDot.requestLayout()
            }
        }
        widthAnimator.start()
    }
```

TabIndicator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <item android:gravity="center">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@color/selected_blue" />
            <size
                android:width="8dp"
                android:height="8dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Goal:

[image]

Reality:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The bug could definitely be related to the</strike>

```
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fillEnabled="true"
```

configurations on the XML. Could you paste the original XML and the container so we can edit our answer and give a more accurate solution to your issue.

Great component by the way, I tested it on my end and it works perfect with this XML config:

```
<!-- For demonstration / testing purposes -->
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/indicator3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tablayout_unselected"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tablayout_selected2"
            app:tabIndicatorAnimationDuration="250"
            app:tabIndicatorAnimationMode="elastic"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/xxxRed"
            app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
            app:tabIndicatorGravity="bottom"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            android:fillAfter="true"
            android:fillEnabled="true"
            app:tabRippleColor="@color/carbon_red_a700"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black"
            app:tabUnboundedRipple="true">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/firstTab"
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/secondTab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/thirdTab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/fourthTab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/fifthTab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

edit1:

I just figured out that even though you didn't provide the `animateDotColor()` function, ChatGPT took a guess and provided this missing function.

It turns out it is exactly this function that's causing the trouble for you, removing the rounded corners.

```
private fun animateDotColor(tabDot: View, fromColor: Int, toColor: Int) {
        val colorAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofObject(
            ArgbEvaluator(),
            ContextCompat.getColor(tabDot.context, fromColor),
            ContextCompat.getColor(tabDot.context, toColor)
        )
        colorAnimator.duration = 500
        colorAnimator.interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
        colorAnimator.addUpdateListener { animation ->
            tabDot.setBackgroundColor(animation.animatedValue as Int)
        }
        colorAnimator.start()
    }
```

Because it's replacing the background of the TabItem().

Solution is instead of setting the color, setting the same background with a different color, so you can preserve the edges and corners. I am going through the same work right now and I will edit a second time and provide you this code as well.

edit2:
Here's the working animateDotColor function for you, this one doesn't remove the corners. Enjoy it buddy.

```
private fun animateDotColor2(tab: TabView, color: Int) {
        tab.background = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(tab.context, R.drawable.tablayout_selected_final)
    }
```